# delete element from priority queue in c++ stl

Tags: c++

Is i have a priority queue with declaration

```
priority_queue<<Node>,vector<Node>,myComp> openQ
```

i am inserting node objects into it. but at some time i have to delete the element from it. (not to remove the top element)

Currently to delete it i am popping the element and putting it in array. if the top most element is desired then expect it i push other elements in array.

This is like linear search and delete. I know its not efficient and i am looking for some better ways

Comment: What problem are you working on?

Comment: wow, that post is terribly confusing...what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have to sort the node object on the basis of its keys, if the node is visited then delete it to optimize

Answer (score 6):

`priority_queue` class is designed for using as queue with priorities. And it designed to remove elements with `pop` function. If you want to get different behavior you should use different class. For instance, `std::map`.

If you're ready to manually control a consistence of the queue you may take a look on `std::make_heap`. It's easy to create a max-heap with it. But in this case you need to manually rebuild a queue each time you want to remove an element.

Comment: That's actually disappointing, so it's uses are limited then.  I need the same thing as mentioned in the question, but have to roll my own it seems.  In my case, I have a PriorityQueue of what I call ConnectionProcessors, which allow my server to do load balancing across the threads (each ConnectionProcessor has a thread running on it); as clients can drop a connection, the PriorityQueue has to be re-ordered, so I have to remove the ConnectionProcessor and re-add it. And the Connection Processor can be anywhere in the priority queue, so the fact that I can't remove it, seem to me, stupid.

Comment: @leetNightshade As I said it was designed that way. If you want take total control over the container you should look at the `std::make_heap` and manage max-heap container manually.

Answer (score 1):

std::set are orderd and can erase elements by value. the underlying datastructure is a binary search tree, thats why its cheaper to erase elements by value.

a priority queue would have to linearly search through the queue, so its possible but just not very efficient, thats why they didnt include it.